# Fenchel conjugate of convex combination of two norms

Tags: proof-explanation, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, non-convex-optimization

Let $\tau \in [0,1]$. Let us define the norm $\Omega(x)=\tau\|x\|_1+(1-\tau)\|x\|_{1,2}$; where
$$
\|x\|_{1,2}=\sqrt{\sum_{g \in \mathcal{G}} \left(\sum_{i \in g} |x_i|\right)^2}
$$
is the exclusive lasso norm. The vector has a group structure; the groups do not have common elements, and the union contains all elements in the vector. It can be shown that the dual norm of $\|x\|_{1,2}$ is the $\|x\|_{\infty,2}$ norm, defined as [1]
$$
\|x\|_{\infty,2}=\sqrt{\sum_{g \in \mathcal{G}} \left(\sup_{i \in g} |x_i|\right)^2}
$$
Let the Fenchel conjugate of $f$ be defined as
$$
f^*(y)=\sup_x
 y^Tx-f(x)\\
\text{ex. }\Omega(x)=\|x\|\\
\text{then }\Omega^*(y)=I_{\|v\|_*\leq1}(y)\text{ where }\\
I_C(x)=
\begin{cases}
    0,& \text{if } x\in C\\
    \infty,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where $\|x\|_*$ is the dual norm of $\|x\|$:
$$
\|x\|_*=\sup_{\|z\|\leq1} z^Tx
$$

My question is, how to derive the Fenchel conjugate for a convex combination of norms?

Using the fact $\Omega^*(y) = (\Omega_1+\Omega_2)^*(y)=\underset{z}{\inf}\Omega_1^*(z)+\Omega_2^*(y-z)$, where $\Omega, \Omega_1, \Omega_2$ are all vector norms, and the scalar multiplication rule:
$$
f(x)=\alpha g(x), f^*(y)=\alpha g^*(y/\alpha)
$$

we arrive at:
$$
f(x)=\tau \|x\|_1, g(x)=(1-\tau) \|x\|_{1,2}\\
\Omega^*(y)=\inf_z f^*(z)+g^*(y-z)=\inf_zI_{\|v\|_{\infty}\leq1}(\frac{z}{\tau})+I_{\|u\|_{\infty,2}\leq1}(\frac{y-z}{1-\tau})
$$
Then I got stuck from here. Ndiaye et. al [2], had a result for convex combination of $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ norms without showing the proof (would be great if someone could show the proof of this, too, since maybe I can adapt this to my original problem):

$$
\Omega(x)=\tau\|x\|_1+(1-\tau)\|x\|_2\\
\Omega^*(y)=\inf_z I_{\|v\|_{\infty}\leq \tau}(z)+I_{\|v\|_{2}\leq 1}(\frac{y-z}{1-\tau})=I_{\|v\|_{2}\leq 1}(\frac{y-\Pi_{\|v\|_{\infty}\leq \tau}(y)}{1-\tau})
$$ where the projection onto the unit $\ell_{\infty}$ ball is defined as
$$
\left[\Pi_{\|v\|_{\infty}\leq 1}(x)\right]_i=
\begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } x_i\geq1\\
    -1,              & \text{if } x_i\leq-1\\
    x_i & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

References:

[1] Campell, Allen, "Within group variable selection through
the Exclusive Lasso", Page 4248

[2] Ndiaye et. al., "GAP Safe Screening Rules for Sparse-Group Lasso", page 15

Answer (score 1):

Let's try a solution "by hand".
Consider $A$ a closed convex set and the optimization problem
$\min_z \iota_A (z) + \iota_B (y - z)$ where $B$ is a set.
Now, note that $0$ is a lower bound and so any $z$ that attains $0$ is optimal.
Define $z^{\star} = \Pi_A(y)$ so that $\iota_A(z^{\star}) = 0$.

1. We have $y - z^{\star} \in B$ implies $\iota_B (y - z^{\star}) = 0$ and $z^{\star}$ is optimal.
2. If $y - z^{\star} \notin B$, the objective goes to infinity. The problem is solved if you can show that $y - z \notin B$ for any other $z \in A$. I am not sure why this should be true. Maybe one need to exploit more information about the sets $A$ and $B$.

Comment: You've described the indicator function of $A+B$ (where this is the Minkowski sum). $(z^*\in A\;\;\text{and}\;\;y-z^*\in B) \Leftrightarrow (z^*\in A\;\;\text{and}\;\;y\in z^*+B)\Leftrightarrow y\in A+B.$